# User defined integer literal not found

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

I am trying to create a user defined literal but get an error message when using it.
GCC says

> unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""_uint’

while clang tells me

> error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""_uint' with argument of type 'unsigned long long' or 'const char *', and no matching literal operator template

I reduced the code to following MCVE:

```
#include <cinttypes>

unsigned int operator"" _uint(char const *, std::size_t) { return 0; }

int main() {
    return 1_uint;
}
```

Which gives the mentioned error as you can see on [ideone](https://ideone.com/qEVrid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in detail on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) there is a multitude of different versions for literal operators.

The one in the OP is used exclusively for string literals and won't be available for integers. Instead the "fallback" version for integers which expects only a `const char*` without a second `std::size_t` parameter:

```
#include <cinttypes>

unsigned int operator"" _uint(char const *) { return 0; }

int main() {
    return 1_uint;
}
```

Which works on [ideone](https://ideone.com/WUvZET).